# What is the cost of refreshing a Realm?

Tags: multithreading, realm

I have read the docs and understand that in many cases you do not need to manually call `refresh` on the `Realm` instance. However, in this pretty common scenario it turned out to be necessary because the completion block may query the Realm before the start of the next run loop.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
        // Add some RLMObjects
    }];

    if (completion) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] refresh]; // necessary if it queries realm
            completion();
        });
    }
});
```

I thought I was being a good citizen by performing write operations on a background thread, but now that I have to call `refresh`, I'm wondering if the overhead involved in this call defeats the point of doing the background processing.

So my questions are:

1) What is the performance cost of calling `refresh` on the `Realm`?

2) Adding just one object to the realm in this pattern probably is 
pointless. After adding how  many objects in this pattern would I see an advantage over the alternative of just performing the write transaction on the main thread synchronously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really great questions!

> 1) What is the performance cost of calling `refresh` on the `Realm`?

*tl;dr; refreshing isn't that expensive*

The cost will be proportionally linear to the number of live "accessors" backed by the `Realm` instance being advanced on that thread. Accessors in Realm Objective-C are `RLMObject`s, `RLMArray`s and `RLMResult`s.

Since Realm uses an [MVCC versioning system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) under the hood, similar to git's inner workings, calling `-[RLMRealm refresh]` is a matter of advancing that Realm's "current transaction pointer" to the latest stable state, much like a `git pull` operation.

It's worth noting that for Realms on a thread with a runloop and with `autorefresh` set to `YES` (which is generally the case for Realms on the main thread), `-[RLMRealm refresh]` will be called automatically at every iteration of the runloop.

So in the vast majority of cases, refreshing a Realm will have a negligible performance impact, unless you have a *very* large number of live "accessors" on that thread.

> 2) Adding just one object to the realm in this pattern probably is pointless. After adding how many objects in this pattern would I see an advantage over the alternative of just performing the write transaction on the main thread synchronously?

*tl;dr; performing writes in the background is safer*

In the vast majority of cases without contention, the overhead to performing a write transaction on the main thread will be below the threshold of 1/60th of a second needed for smooth UIs. *However* writes in Realm are *blocking*, which means that if there's a large write transaction happening concurrently in the background, this will block the main thread when writing from the main thread concurrently, which is less than ideal because it causes UIs to stutter or block.

For this reason, we recommend that all write transactions, no matter how small and fast, be performed on a background thread unless you're sure there won't be any contention.

I realize that performing writes on a background thread is complicated by Realm's strict thread confinement enforcement of accessors, which is why we're tracking adding APIs for asynchronous writes allowing the safe handover of accessors across threads in [#3136](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3136).

Since read operations in Realm aren't blocked by other reads or writes (thanks to MVCC mentioned above!), it's perfectly acceptable to perform those on any thread.

Comment: Very informative answer, thank you!  I will continue to use the background writes pattern then.

Comment: @jpsim how about using the transactionWithBlock inside another block like networking success/failure block is it better than the usual commit transaction ?

Comment: transactionWithBlock is literally just a shortcut for beginWriteTransaction & commitWriteTransaction